# Excel Pivot Table - ID and Name on same line

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a excel file of flat data with:

ID, Name, Location, Department, Sun(Hours), Mon, Tue, Wed, Thr, Fri, Sat, Reg Hrs, OT Hrs

When I insert a pivot table, the rows are broken up by Location, within Location - Department and within Department - Name.
The column info is the daily hours and the Reg and OT totals.  They are summed for each Department.

I'd like to have the ID and Name combined as a row label.  But when I add ID it duplicates the hours info onto a second line.

How can I combine the Name and ID fields onto one line?

Comment: either way is fine.  I'll check out that site. I just can't imagine I would need to combine the ID and Name fields in my source data.

Comment: Play with the Report Layout. If you still need help after that, please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

as per https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2249-excel-pivot-table-row-labels-on-same-line.html, under the `PivotTable Tools` tab, click `Design` > `Report Layout` > `Show in Tabular Form`